# MS Report Builder 3.0 Set same color for whole series

Tags: reporting-services, charts, reporting, ssrs-2012, reportbuilder

I have a `chart` where on `X axis` is `date` and on `Y axis` is some `number`.
I have a `3 values` on each `series`, where `series`, for example, is a data `by customer`, so i want set unique `color` for whole `series` (`customer`) so all `values` on chart are `blue`, for example, but with different `line style`, one is `solid`, another `dotted` etc.
Also i don't know what `series` on the chart so i can't just write some `switch` statements to define `colors`.

I haven't found any option to `get color` of another `Field` in expression.

Is there any option to do this? Or only option to generate for each value based on `series` (`CustomerID`)?

Here is sample data:

```
WITH CTE AS(
    select '2015-11-01' [Date], 1 CustomerID, 10 Value1, 15 Value2
    union
    select '2015-11-02' [Date], 1 CustomerID, 15 Value1, 12 Value2
    union
    select '2015-11-03' [Date], 1 CustomerID, 17 Value1, 13 Value2
    union
    select '2015-11-01' [Date], 2 CustomerID, 25 Value1, 10 Value2
    union
    select '2015-11-02' [Date], 2 CustomerID, 22 Value1, 13 Value2
    union
    select '2015-11-03' [Date], 2 CustomerID, 15 Value1, 20 Value2
    union
    select '2015-11-01' [Date], 3 CustomerID, 15 Value1, 30 Value2
    union
    select '2015-11-02' [Date], 3 CustomerID, 19 Value1, 20 Value2
    union
    select '2015-11-03' [Date], 3 CustomerID, 12 Value1, 9 Value2
)
select
    CustomerID,
    [Date]
    ,CrossApplied.Val
    ,CrossApplied.Num
from CTE
CROSS APPLY 
   (VALUES (Value1, 1),
           (Value2, 2))
    CrossApplied (Val, Num)
```

And the `Chart`:
[image: Chart what i have now]

And `Chart Settings`:
[image: Settings]

So as you can see, every `Customer` have 2 `Values`, I want this `Values` to be same the `color` on the chart. Like lines 1 - 1 and 1 - 2 have same color (`Blue`), 2 - 1 and 2 - 2 have `Red` color etc.

Comment: Edit your question to include a screenshot of the chart you are getting now.

Comment: @alejandro i've added example.

Comment: I've update my answer based on your comments.

Answer (score 1):

If the field used to group series is variable the first think comes to my mind was add another column that lets you separate each group in order to get every `Customer` with different type of border line.

I recreated your scenario with this sample data:

**UPDATE**: Edition based on your comments.

```
WITH CTE AS(
    select '2015-11-01' [Date], 1 CustomerID, 10 Value1, 15 Value2
    union
    select '2015-11-02' [Date], 1 CustomerID, 15 Value1, 12 Value2
    union
    select '2015-11-03' [Date], 1 CustomerID, 17 Value1, 13 Value2
    union
    select '2015-11-01' [Date], 2 CustomerID, 25 Value1, 10 Value2
    union
    select '2015-11-02' [Date], 2 CustomerID, 22 Value1, 13 Value2
    union
    select '2015-11-03' [Date], 2 CustomerID, 15 Value1, 20 Value2
    union
    select '2015-11-01' [Date], 3 CustomerID, 15 Value1, 30 Value2
    union
    select '2015-11-02' [Date], 3 CustomerID, 19 Value1, 20 Value2
    union
    select '2015-11-03' [Date], 3 CustomerID, 12 Value1, 9 Value2
)
select
    CustomerID,
    [Date]
    ,CrossApplied.Val
    ,CrossApplied.Num
    ,DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY CustomerID) as GroupNumber
from CTE
CROSS APPLY 
   (VALUES (Value1, 1),
           (Value2, 2))
    CrossApplied (Val, Num)
```

[image]

If you want to have different color for every `CustomerID` **You have to add** [DENSE_RANK()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173825.aspx) by `CustomerID` add this line as a new column to your query (check the above query):

```
DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY CustomerID) as GroupNumber
```

Now you have a column `GroupNumber` that lets you identify the group which a CustomerID belongs to.

This is a possible data arrangement in a line chart

[image]

To get different different line color per `CustomerID` I am using `GroupNumber` field.

```
=CHOOSE(Fields!GroupNumber.Value,"Blue","Red","Green","Black","Yellow")
```

> Add the number of colors based on the quantity of different `CustomerID` you have, in my example I added 5 colors so each `CustomerID` will take one color for draw its line..

This will produce the following chart.

[image]

In this example my query generates 3 different `CustomerID` so it will show the lines in three different colors. The first three in the `CHOOSE` expression: Blue, Red and Green. The colors black and yellow are not being used cause there are no more different `CustomerID`.

Let me know if this can help you.

Comment: Thank @alejandro for your reply, this is helpfull, but i can't select a color for series, becaurse i don't know what `CustomerID` will be in the report. Also in your basic data every customer have unique ID `GroupNumber` and in my real case, every value have its own `GroupNumber` like:
CustomerID | Date | Value | Group
1 | d1 | x1 | 1
1 | d1 | x2 | 2
2 | d1 | x1 | 1
2 | d1 | x2 | 2
1 | d2 | x1 | 1
1 | d2 | x2 | 2
2 | d2 | x1 | 1
2 | d2 | x2 | 2

Comment: So i want to have your first and second chart at one chart. So to every `Customer` assigned it unique colour and every `Value` have this `unique color` but different `border color`.
Is there any way add additional line at chart without adding new `Series`?

Comment: as i said, I don't know exact number of customers, it's roughly about 15 but i can't just write `CHOOSE` cuz it's more than 5. Is there any possibility to recreate  `Automatic` color generation which is set by default so i can generate color based on `GroupNumber` and not on actual value?

Comment: @Towelie,Using Palette colors will draw every line of a different color my suggestion is set as many colors as you want in the `CHOOSE` expression. You can put 30 colors or more however I doubt you want to show 30 lines in this kind of chart.